# WebView LoadRequest before UINavigationBar setHidden is YES

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I need to make the navigation bar HIDDEN in a view controller. I do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But when I need to start a new thread to load webview when the app is launched,

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self)
       [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(doStuff) toTarget:self withObject:NULL];
   return self;
}

- (void)doStuff
{
   NSLog(@"Starting a new thread ...");

   url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [newsWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

the navigation bar still appears.

I just want to make the navigationbar hidden and load the webview in separate thread in this view controller when the app is launched. When I tap the tabBar, this viewController will be ready for user to view.

May I know what is the problem? or I'm doing it in the wrong way? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide the **navigationBar** in the parent or it's previous view when you try to navigate to this view and the problem is solved like this

**Assume that this view is navigated when some button is clicked in previous view**

in button's action method put this line before navigate to the current view

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

hi i think it is better to place this line of code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

in method

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

I hope it will work it out.